# How can I stop KDE from changing laptop screen brightness every time I plug and unplug the power?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kde, laptop

According do their [forum](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=168584) I can change it in Hardware -> Power Management, but I don't have that option in my settings.

Fresh KDE install on Arch Linux

Answer (score 0):

Install [`powerdevil`](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/powerdevil/) package. It adds power related settings in KDE System Settings.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]